# FormatException: Invalid date format 2018-08-1

Tags: datetime, flutter, dart

If I write, in DartPad, `print(DateTime.parse("2012-12-12"));` it works. So why doesn't it work when I do the following (it reports an "invalid date format"):

```dart
  for (int i = 1; i <= 28; i = i + 7) {
    _activities[DateTime.parse('2012-12-$i')] = activityNames.toList();
  }
```

Comment: can you share the complete error message ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add this to your package’s `pubspec.yaml` file:

https://pub.dev/packages/intl#-readme-tab-

dependencies:

> intl: ^0.16.0

```
 var now = new DateTime.now();
 print(new DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(now));
```

For more should go for this :https://androidkt.com/format-datetime-in-flutter/

Answer (score 12):

Because DateTime.parse, expects 4 digits for Year, 2 digits for month, and 2 digits for day. In your for loop i begins as 1 which is a number below 9 so since it's a single digit number he parse function is not receiving the expected input. Hence, the compilation issue.I know this is mad late but I hope this helps somebody.

Comment: No you're not late. and this is the correct explanation for the error. Thanks